# Extract characters from a string in only one line

Tags: python, regex

Edited based on feedback:
Usually when I want to extract a portion of a string I do this:

```
match = re.search('ma(\w)ch', 'match')
if match :
  whatIWant = match.group(1)
```

This is 3 lines. I'd prefer to do something like this:

```
if re.search('ma(\w)ch', 'match'):
  whatIWant = $_.group(1)
```

At least that's two lines. Or even better,

```
whatIWant = re.search('ma(\w)ch', 'match').group(1)
```

Ideally it would be nice to be able to do it, even in a list comprehension. A list of strings. Which would require one line. Is that possible?

Here is my actual code I'm working on now. But I'm interested in general regex expression shortening as well. Which is why I gave the general example above.

```
observeStr = ['ch1', 'dq_23']
dqMatches = ['dq_*(\d+)', 'tx_*(\d+)', 'rx_*(\d+)']
dword = [re.search(dqMatch, el.lower()) for el in observeStr for dqMatch in dqMatches if re.search(dqMatch, el.lower())]
if len(dword) == 1:
  observeStr += ['dword {0}'.format(int(dword[0].group(1)) / 32)]
```

Comment: In Python 3.8 you will have assignment expressions: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/

Comment: What do you want to be in `whatIWant` if the match fails? `None`? Whatever was there before? Or do you want an exception to be raised? The last one is already exactly what happens. The first one, you can write a trivial wrapper function that does that. Pretty much anything you want is easy, but if you don't know what you want, it's impossible.

Comment: Also, what does "a list of strings" refer to? `search` will never return a list of anything. And what multiple strings are you expecting? Are there lots of matches in the fine, so you're looking for `re.findall` or `re.finditer`? Or something different?

Answer (score 1):

Your example boils down to

```
't' if 't' in 'match' else None
```

assuming that `None` is what you for `what_i_want` in the case of no matches. Indeed, if all you need to do is pick out characters, you probably won't need `re` at all.

In the more general case where you do need `re`, if you want to cut it down to two lines, you could do

```
match = re.search('ma(t)ch', 'match')
what_i_want = match.group(1) if match else None
```

In the near future, you get something close to what you wish for in your preferred solution as [PEP 572 (Assignment Expressions)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) mentions your example as a concrete use case:

> Case in point: Guido found several examples where a programmer repeated a subexpression, slowing down the program, in order to save one line of code, e.g. instead of writing:
>
> ```
> match = re.match(data)
> group = match.group(1) if match else None
> ```
>
> they would write:
>
> ```
> group = re.match(data).group(1) if re.match(data) else None
> ```

The functionality will be available in Python 3.8 with which you can write your example as

```
if match := re.search('ma(t)ch', 'match'):
    what_i_want = match.group(1)
```

Comment: you're right my example allows for a simpler expression. What I should have given as an example is : `match = re.search('ma(\w)ch', 'match')` A case with an unknown value I'm trying to capture. THank you!